# Accessing UEFI settings on Windows 8 laptop now running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, uefi

We have bought a couple of new laptops that came with Windows 8 (Toshiba L870) but we don't use Win8 at work so have rebuilt with Win7 (with Secure Boot turned off).

Does anyone know how to get into the UEFI system manager to make changes? We did it originally via Windows 8 itself.

Comment: You access the configuration menu the same way you always have accessed bios.  I would check the manual for the laptop.

Comment: Hmmm, there was a user guide in the box, but it was pathetic! I've tried the default for other Toshiba laptops to get into the BIOS but they don't seem to work. It doesn't display anything at the Toshiba logo screen either.

Answer (score -1):

Check the BIOS manual and it may clue you in on how to get into the UEFI BIOS.  On my MSI board I get to the BIOS with <kbd>DEL</kbd> or the Boot menu with <kbd>F11</kbd>.

I did this on my desktop PC running Windows 7 Ultimate. Your manual should have similar instructions.

Comment: This really isn't an answer.  More specific advice for his laptop would be welcome.